# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (SearchCity.java:56) (SearchCity.java:104)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
public class SearchCity {

    public void tc() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://localhost/allmapview/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        ArrayList<String> data0 = readExcelData(0);
        ArrayList<String> data1 = readExcelData(1);

        for(int i=0; i<data0.size(); i++) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='from']")).sendKeys(data0.get(i));
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='to']")).sendKeys(data1.get(i));
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calculate-route']/div[3]/div/div[2]/button")).click();
            Thread.sleep(8000);

            String strText = driver.findElement(By.id("google_dt")).getText();
            String strText1 = driver.findElement(By.id("mmi_dt_2")).getText();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Screenshots\\Book1.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(strText);
            XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(1);
            XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(3);
            cell2.setCellValue(strText1);
            fis.close();
            FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\\\Screenshots\\\\Book1.xlsx"));
                workbook.write(fos);
                fos.close();


            File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new
                    File("D:\\Screenshots\\Screen" +i));
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calculate-route']/div[3]/div/div[3]/input")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);



        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> readExcelData(int colNo) throws IOException {
        File src = new File("D:\\Screenshots\\Book1.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet1.iterator();
        rowIterator.next();

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            list.add(rowIterator.next().getCell(colNo).getStringCellValue());
        }


        System.out.println("List :::"+list);
        return list;

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SearchCity city = new SearchCity();
        city.tc();
```

I have written a code to read an excel file to fill some entries in a webpage and I want to fetch some data from that webpage and write it into my excel sheet, but I got `NullPointerException` in my code at different lines, and it is not a duplicate question I think, so please suggest some answers.

> Exception in thread "main" java lang NullPointerException
>         at SearchCity SearchCity tc(SearchCity java:56)
>         at SearchCity SearchCity main(SearchCity java:104)

Comment: @VPK its `city.tc();` line 56 is more important

Comment: i guess the problem is around here `FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\\\Screenshots\\\\Book1.xlsx"));
                workbook.write(fos);
                fos.close();`

Comment: @shivam, your exception is basically thrown at line `56`. What is the code at that line? Please check by debugging if you are trying to access the elements on `null` object.

Comment: cell.setCellValue(strText); this is the line 56

Comment: suggest me an solution

Comment: This means, `cell` is `null`. Try to debug if the row has the cell at index `2`. You can provide a check using `if` statement like - `if (row.getCell(2) != null)` and then do the corresponding operations.

Comment: yes you are right, so what is the solution for that?

Comment: @shivam, have you tried the below solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First thing, you are reading the same row twice in your code `XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);` and in `XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(1);`. This is not required. Then, you need to check whether the `sheet` is null and `sheet.getRow(1)` to be on safer side. Next, read the row and check if the cells are `null`, if not, then set the value.

This could be the solution to your particular problem,

```
if (sheet != null && sheet.getRow(1) != null) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(1);

    if (row.getCell(2) != null) {
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(strText);
    }

    if (row.getCell(3) != null) {
        XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(3);
        cell2.setCellValue(strText1);
    }
}
```

Comment: code is running fine but excel file is not updated with strText and strText1

Comment: Try to debug the code and check if the rows have cells. If the cells are null, value could not be updated.

Comment: @shivam, by the way, it would be a different question as to why the file is not being updated. If your initial problem of `NullPointerException` has solved, you can mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: You shouldn't have to check if every single workbook access is `null`.

Comment: @JeffC, it's just for `to be on the safer side` I said in the answer. However, how are you supposed to avoid `NPE`?